# Getting login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\CoreApplications' even with username password

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2012

I'm getting the following error

> Database Error: Cannot open database "TrendingDB" requested by
> the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS
> APPPOOL\CoreApplications'.

Even if I have a username password on my connection string. I use the same applications on the same 3 different environments, except that when I deployed the same application on another environment with it's own appsettings, it would give me the above error.

Not sure what I missed on the setup with this current environment. The username is verified to exist and can log in using the password. Also double checked the access to execute the stored procedure it's calling from the API.

The application is a .NET Core API.

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "Environment": "UAT",
        "ConnectionString": "server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;database=TrendingDB;Connect Timeout=120;Trusted_Connection=True;User=webservice;Password=trending123"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a wild stab in the dark, but it looks like IIS is trying to do the login, perhaps double check your Pass-through authentication on your API in IIS under basic Settings and Test Settings... since in your connection string it is User=webservice so why is it failing for user  'IIS APPPOOL\CoreApplications'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify `Trusted_Connection=True` in your connection string. This uses the Windows Identity for the process and ignores any username and password you specify in the connection string. Remove that, so your connection string looks like

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "Environment": "UAT",
        "ConnectionString": "server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;database=TrendingDB;Connect Timeout=120;User=webservice;Password=trending123"
    }
}
```

Comment: wow that worked! but here's a follow up though, i use the same formats on the other servers and it worked without any issues. wonder why  this specific one yells at me?

Comment: It might be those database installations just don’t support trusted connections